# Axis2 REST : POST Parameters Null

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, apache-axis, phase

i am using Axis2 as a REST webservice to a mobile app, i am writing a Handler for security that goes into a custom phase of the Axis2 IN flow, and i am having some troubles getting the POST parameters from the request; I am able to successfully retrieve those parameters when using a GET method, but in POST case, all i am getting is null values.
Any help is highly appreciated

here is my code snippet :

```
public InvocationResponse invoke(MessageContext mc) throws AxisFault {
    AxisMessage axisMessage = mc.getAxisMessage();

    System.out.println("***SecurityHandler Starting***");
    HttpServletRequest req =(HttpServletRequest)mc.getProperty(HTTPConstants.MC_HTTP_SERVLETREQUEST);
    System.out.println("Method : "+req.getMethod());

    String username = req.getParameter(ARG_LOGIN);
    System.out.println("User login : "+ username);// User login : null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpServletRequest obj = (HttpServletRequest)msgContext .
                                            getProperty("transport.http.servletRequest");
  if (obj != null) {
   System.out.println("Method :"+ obj.getMethod());
   System.out.println("Content-type :" +obj.getContentType());
   System.out.println("Content-length :"+obj.getContentLength());
   System.out.println("Remote addtress"+obj.getSession().getLastAccessedTime());  
  }
```

Check this post[1]

[1] http://vvratha.blogspot.com/2013/08/extracting-http-level-information-in.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the constant  `HTTPConstants.MC_HTTP_SERVLETREQUEST` value is `"transport.http.servletRequest"`, my problem is specifically with the POST parameters; `obj.getParameter(ARG_LOGIN)` is `null`, all the other values are fine (Method, ContentType, ContentLength ...)

I might be wrong but it's like at the moment i'm intercepting the flow, the parameters are not parsed yet